# Convert a number entered in a textbox to double in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, type-conversion

I am typing a series of numbers(double) separated by space into a textbox and i want to perform some simple division on these numbers after getting it from the textbox. This is my code. There is an error that says 'Operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'double'.

```
    public string[] arrayvalues = new string[100];
    public static double[] arraydivide = new double[100];
    arrayvalues = text2.Text.Split(' ');
    arrayvalues[i]/arraydivide[i];
```

so i am converting the string 'arrayvalues' to double using the below code and storing the calculated value into another double array

```
   arrayanother[i] = Convert.ToDouble(arrayvalues[i])/arraydivide[i];
```

When i try to print the value of 'arrayanother' i get an error -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WpfApplication1.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Basically i am not able to convert the string of numbers to 'double'. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What is `i` in your arrays?

Comment: Where are you printing the array content?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < arrayvalues.Length; i++)

Comment: Normally, you'd just bind the `TextBox.Text` property to some `Double` property. WPF will take care of the data conversion for you. Unfortunately, the question is not very clear; without XAML, it hardly even seems like a WPF question. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Your Index is out of range, so i guess there is something wrong with your loop.  The element which you are calling in your arrays somewhere is empty.

Comment: Did you initialise `arrayanother`?

Comment: what is 'i'?? where is it starting from??